# Delete from list of files in firebase using refFromURL

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I've searched all over the internet but I'm unable to delete a file from storage using refFromURL in firebase v9. I tried using firebase.storage().refFromURL(url) to fetch the path but its states that firebase.storage is not a function. Is their any work around in firebase v9?

```
  const deleteGalleryImage = (attachment, index) => {
    // console.log(getRefFromURL(attachment));
    let pictureRef =  firebase.storage().refFromURL(attachment);
    pictureRef
      .delete()
      .then(() => {
        setAttachments(attachments.filter((image) => image !== attachment));
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using v9 then you can't use the namespace `refFromUrl` method anymore. The equivalent operation is now built into the top-level [`ref` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#ref).

So to get a ref from a URL, you'd do something like:

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();

const storageRef = ref(storage, "your URL here");
```