# Firebase storage delete image by downloadURL V9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

I'm trying to delete an image from Firebase storage in React Native by downloadURL. Also i'm using web V9.
Writing down most essential chuncks of code:

```
import {
  deleteObject,
  getStorage,
  ref
} from "firebase/storage";

...
// DownloadURL
const photo = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com.... ";

const storage = getStorage();
...
const storageRef = ref(storage, photo);
deleteObject(storageRef)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("File deleted successfully");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

My code is inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71640886/delete-from-list-of-files-in-firebase-using-reffromurl) and I got this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: The
> operation 'deleteObject' cannot be performed on a root reference,
> create a non-root reference using child, such as .child('file.png').
> (storage/invalid-root-operation)]
> I'm little confused.

**Later edit:**

My function which upload the image and get the download url:

```
    // uri is returned from "expo-image-picker"
    const uploadImageAsync = async (uri) => {
        // manipulateAsync imported from 'expo-image-manipulator'
        const manipResult = await manipulateAsync(uri, [], {
          compress: 0.6,
          format: "jpeg",
        });
        const response = await fetch(manipResult.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        
            const imageName = Date.now().toString();
            const fileRef = ref(storage, `avatar/${user.uid}/${imageName}.jpg`);
            const result = await uploadBytes(fileRef, blob);
        
            getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((snapshot) => {
              // downloadURL is added to Redux state to be used later
              dispatch(addPhoto(snapshot));
            });
          };
```

Comment: The code seems correct. What is your Firebase version? Also can you share complete code so we can see where the `downloadURL` is coming from or you've just hardcoded the URL?

Comment: Could you please check the url on the variable `photo`. That error would appear if it's a reference to your storage bucket. e.g.: `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<PROJECT-ID>.appspot.com/o/`

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB You're right. That's how my url looks. Please explain me how can I get the correct url? I attached above the function which set the downloadURL.

Comment: @Dharmaraj my Firebase version is: "firebase": "^9.6.2". A lot of code lines will be irelevant for this question. I updated my question by adding the function which get downloadURL. Are you suggest to update Firebase to latest version(9.6.11) ?

Comment: The code it works guys only by a server restart. Thanks for your support. Appreciate.